# Why the second param of AppRegistry.registerComponent is function?

Tags: react-native

As we all know, if you want to set entrance of app, you will do like this：

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App1', () => App1);

Why does the second param is `() => App1` instead of `App1`, and `() => App1` does nothing actually except return `App1`.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is a function. It doesn't just do nothing, you said it yourself - it returns your component.

When RN renders the app, it uses this function to get the component that gets rendered in the app container.
That's simply how it was implemented.

Comment: So what's the advantage using function instead of a variable?